# Cumulative count but not if already seen, then assign previous count value

Tags: python, count, cumulative-sum

Currently I only have the first column, how can I create the second column?   Something with cumulative count. If a item already has been seen, then don't cumulative  count, but place the already assigned value there. For example, c & d in the table below.

df['Order Number'] = ?

| Item | Order Number |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
| e | 5 |
| f | 6 |
| g | 7 |

Comment: This question would benefit from showing a sample of your desired output.

Comment: Hi, my desired outcome is the second column!

Comment: `df['Order Number'] = df.groupby('Item').ngroup()+1`

Comment: Hi thank you Chris, and what if they are not in an alphabetical order?

Comment: Then sort it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on answer from Chris. Change sort to True if you want it in alphabetical order.

```
import pandas as pd

dict_d = {'Item': ['b', 'a','c','d','c','d','e','b','f','g']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict_d)
df['Order Number'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Item',sort=False)).ngroup()+1

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Item  Order Number
0    b             1
1    a             2
2    c             3
3    d             4
4    c             3
5    d             4
6    e             5
7    b             1
8    f             6
9    g             7
```

Edit: To incorporate another column, simply add another grouper. For example.

```
import pandas as pd

dict_d = {'Item': ['b', 'a','c','d','c','d','e','b','f','g'],
            'User_ID': ['111', '231','431','333','132','345','253','111','335','999']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict_d)
df['Order Number'] = df.groupby([
    pd.Grouper(key='Item',sort=False),
    pd.Grouper(key='User_ID',sort=False)
]).ngroup()+1

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Item User_ID  Order Number
0    b     111             2
1    a     231             1
2    c     431             4
3    d     333             5
4    c     132             3
5    d     345             6
6    e     253             7
7    b     111             2
8    f     335             8
9    g     999             9
```